# Mail Chimp IF statement

Tags: if-statement, rss, conditional-statements, mailchimp, feed

I am trying to set up specific RSS feeds to subscribers based on region selection.  I am attempting to use a Conditional Merge Tag Block.  What I have below will not work and I am not sure why.

What I expect to get is the tile text (eg. North American News Headlines) and the RSS feed titles depending the region of the campaign recipient.  The recipient has set their region via the sign-up form i.e `REGION = North America`.  If the recipient's region is set to `North America`, it displays everything correctly until the first `*|IFELSE:REGION` tag then it just displays the code.

```
*|IF:REGION = No Region|*News Headlines Offline
No headlines for you...Your region is not set.*|ELSEIF:REGION = North America|*
North American News Headlines

*|FEEDBLOCK:https://globalvoicesonline.org/-/world/north-america/feed/|**|FEEDITEMS:|*
*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|**|END:FEEDITEMS|**|END:FEEDBLOCK|**|ELSEIF:REGION = European Union|*
European Union News Headlines

*|FEEDBLOCK:https://globalvoicesonline.org/-/world/western-europe/feed/|**|FEEDITEMS:|*
*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|**|END:FEEDITEMS|**|END:FEEDBLOCK|**|ELSEIF:REGION = Africa|*
African News Headlines

*|FEEDBLOCK:https://globalvoicesonline.org/-/world/sub-saharan-africa/feed/|**|FEEDITEMS:|*
*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|**|END:FEEDITEMS|**|END:FEEDBLOCK|**|ELSEIF:REGION = East Asia|*
East Asian News Headlines

*|FEEDBLOCK:https://globalvoicesonline.org/-/world/east-asia/feed/|**|FEEDITEMS:|*
*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|**|END:FEEDITEMS|**|END:FEEDBLOCK|**|ELSEIF:REGION = South Asia|*
South Asian News Headlines

*|FEEDBLOCK:https://globalvoicesonline.org/-/world/south-asia/feed/|**|FEEDITEMS:|*
*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|**|END:FEEDITEMS|**|END:FEEDBLOCK|**|ELSEIF:REGION = Central America / Caribbean|*
Central American/Caribbean News Headlines

*|FEEDBLOCK:https://globalvoicesonline.org/-/world/caribbean/feed/|**|FEEDITEMS:|*
*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|**|END:FEEDITEMS|**|END:FEEDBLOCK|**|ELSEIF:REGION = Eastern Europe / Russia|*
Eastern Europe/Russia News Headlines

*|FEEDBLOCK:https://globalvoicesonline.org/-/world/eastern-central-europe/feed|**|FEEDITEMS:|*
*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|**|END:FEEDITEMS|**|END:FEEDBLOCK|**|ELSEIF:REGION = Middle East|*
Middle East News Headlines

*|FEEDBLOCK:https://globalvoicesonline.org/-/world/middle-east-north-africa/feed/|**|FEEDITEMS:|*
*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|**|END:FEEDITEMS|**|END:FEEDBLOCK|**|ELSEIF:REGION = Oceania|*
Oceania News Headlines

*|FEEDBLOCK:https://globalvoicesonline.org/-/world/oceania/feed/|**|FEEDITEMS:|*
*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|**|END:FEEDITEMS|**|END:FEEDBLOCK|**|ELSEIF:REGION = South America|*
South American News Headlines

*|FEEDBLOCK:https://globalvoicesonline.org/-/world/latin-america/feed/|**|FEEDITEMS:|*
*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|**|END:FEEDITEMS|**|END:FEEDBLOCK|**|ELSE|*nil*|END:IF|*
Your region is set to *|REGION|*.  Change Region >>
```

Comment: Sorry we don't understand **What I have below will not work**. Please explain what you expect to get, and what you currently get with the above code.

Comment: What I expect to get is the tile text (eg. North American News Headlines) and the RSS feed titles depending the region of the campaign recipient.  The recipient has set their region via the sign-up form i.e `REGION = North America`.  If the recipient's region is set to `North America`, it displays eveything correctly until the first `*|IFELSE:REGION` tag then it just displays the code.

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31163220/edit) and add the additional information there so people can understand the problem you're getting and you'll hopefully get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're entering the conditional mergetag block in the source code view of Mailchimp's text editor. It's got a nasty habit of splicing formatting markup in the middle of mergetags, so that your conditional mergetags look perfect in preview mode but actually the code looks like this:
   `*|ELSE</span>IF: Region = North America|*`

Which obviously won't work too well, but will look like it works in the preview of the email. Just flick to code view and make sure there's no random code in the middle of the mergetags.

Might not apply to your problem, but it has caused me an identical result to the one you describe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @daffdy but wasn't the case here.